# What is a Generalised plant (interconnected system)

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

I am studying control theory and I was introduced to generalised plant. I find it very difficult to find resources to explain the idea with sufficient details.
What I understand is that the generalised plant is a way of expressing every block diagram.

Can someone provide me with any resources please because I am really confused.

I undertand in this questions I dont provide any information, I just dont understand how the block diagrams can be modelled in the same way of a generalised plant.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A generalized plant is simply a plant that has two types of inputs and two types of outputs.

The two types of inputs are the control input and the disturbance input. Some of the latter type may come from an uncertainty block and this will be the case where we express an uncertain system as a Linear Fractional Representation (or also called LFT form, with a slight abuse of language).

The two types of outputs are the measured outputs and the controlled outputs, which may differ depending on the context. Note that part of the controlled outputs may contain outputs that will enter an uncertainty block in the LFT form of the system.

Any resource on robust control and loop-shaping will cover that. For instance, the books by Paganini and Dullerud, or the book by Zhou, Doyle and Glover, etc.

Comment: And the control goal is generally minimizing the effect of disturbance inputs (e.g. noise, uncertainty, disturbance, etc.) on controlled outputs (e.g. reference error). Which quantity refers to which type of input / output depends on the problem and is the designer's choice.